# golang: why does terminal stdout not print out utf-8 characters?

Tags: vim, go, iterm

So `golang` is designed to handle unicode/utf-8 properly.

However, I seem to have problem getting utf-8 characters printed out in my terminal's standard output correctly.

The simplest program here:-

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
}
```

when executed, shows encoded characters.

```
$ go run hello.go
Hello, ‰∏ñÁïå
```

My terminal's locale is set correctly:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

and I am using vim with `set encoding=utf-8` and `set fileencodings=utf-8` included in my `.vimrc` file.

This might actually be a `vim` problem. I used `nano` to write this script from scratch and name it `hello2.go` and the print out actually prints `Hello, 世界` correctly. But the original `hello.go` script, created with `vim`, only gives me the gibberish `Hello, ‰∏ñÁïå`.

So just double check that my vim-created `hello.go` script is a UTF-8 Unicode text, I run the `file` command on it. Like this:-

```
$ file hello.go
hello.go: C source, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

So what gives?  Why does my vim created `hello.go` script above print out gibberish but my nano created `hello2.go` (which contains the same exact lines of code) does not?

```
$ file hello2.go
hello2.go: C source, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

In fact, when I open vim-created `hello.go` with `nano`, the source code now reads:-

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello ‰∏ñÁïå")
}
```

But if I open the same vim-created `hello.go` with `vim`, the source code reads:-

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
}
```

Why is this so?

Comment: And you've verified that this only happens with a Go program? It prints fine for me.

Comment: No. I don't think this is a golang problem after further review. It's most likely an `iTerm2` problem.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be related to Vim either.

Comment: @mihai this might actually be a `vim` problem. I used `nano` to write this script from scratch and the print out actually prints `Hello, 世界` correctly. But when I create this `hello.go` script with `vim`, I get the gibberish print out again!

Comment: @CalvinCheng: If you run `file hello.go`, does it say it's UTF-8 text?

Comment: Yes. See update above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the offending lines in my `.vimrc` that is causing me this problem.

```
if has("gui_running")
    set guitablabel=%t%=%m  "Set the label of the tabs
    set nomacatsui anti enc=utf-8 tenc=macroman gfn=Monaco:h11
    " set window size
    set lines=40
    set columns=120
else
    set enc=utf-8 tenc=macroman gfn=Monaco:h11
    set fenc=utf-8
endif
```

Specifically, `tenc=macroman` is screwing up my encoding at terminal level.

Switched it to `tenc=utf-8` and all is good.

Wasted 4 hours of my life on this I-should-have-seen-this-coming problem! Ugh.

Comment: What did you change `tenc` to -- or did you just take it out? I'm thinking you could mark this as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is related to Font used in Windows "Command Prompt" (Console) tool properties.

Click on menu icon in top left corner, select "Properties", 
then "Font" tab. On my Windows 8.1 machine default was "Raster Font" and I was getting question marks ????? instead of Unicode characters, encoded by UTF8 in Go Lang program.

The solution is to select one of TrueType fonts, "Consolas" or "Lucida Console"